# How to transfer the transaction gas to the user

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, erc20

I´m developing a NFT game with ER20 token. When the player plays the game it earns token. After some time, the player can withdraw the amount of tokens that are inside the game and send to your metamask wallet.

To do that, my backend signs the transaction with the private key of the owner and send tokens to the player (i´m paying the gas because i´m doing this transaction).

But I want to transfer the gas fees to the player. How can I do this strategy?

There are a lot of NFT games that implements this strategy right now, but I don´t know how to use web3 and solidity to do that.

Comment: Which gas fees do you want to transfer?

Comment: gas fees relates with every withdraw that player claim. Every claim the contract needs to pay gas fee in order to transfer tokens from wallet to player.

Comment: i didn't understood, the balance of the user is off-chain (like on a db) and when a user do a withdraw you want to delete balance from db and send the amount withdrawn from your wallet to the user wallet, right?

Comment: @JacopoMosconi yes. you are right. if I have 3000 players I need to pay gas fee for everyone. How deal with it?

Comment: I think that in this casee you don't want to send a gas fee to each player (wich you can send wei) but you want to pay the gas fee for a withdrawal. As you said, just have a backend that checks for withdrawals and make a withdrawal server-side to avoid your player paying a gas fee. Sending the necessary ether to each player would be very inefficient.

Comment: @NuMa I would like to do the opposite. i would like to send the gas fee to the user, because if I have 1K user I  should have enough money to pay that.